# Jquery Flot get ticks data for tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using the jquery flot to show charts with tooltip. I am using ticks to get custom xaxis data. SO

```
 var data = [ [0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5],  [9, 13] ];
 var ticksData = [ [0, "A"], [4, "B"], [8, "C"],  [9, "D"] ];
 ......
 xaxis: {            
         ticks: ticksData,
         tickLength: 0
     },
```

But when I want to show the tooltip, I got the none `ticks` data.

```
 $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
      var x = item.datapoint[0],   y = item.datapoint[1];
      //x and y are 4,8 instead of B,8
```

Complete sample http://jsfiddle.net/z0u6rqhe/

Is there any way to get to fix tool tip to show ticks data, or I should loop through `ticksData` and re find the value

Comment: Dear @AdnanUmer, I expect to have `x:B` and `y:8`.  As I mentioned I want the xaxis ticks data.

Comment: You have to find the tick value yourself. There is no built-in method in flot for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this link, i hope this will helpful for you.

```
jsfiddle.net/z0u6rqhe/5/
```

code:

```
  var x = item.series.xaxis.ticks[item.dataIndex];
```

Comment: Exactly! Please copy the key part of your answer here too!